# How to color big sentence in xlsxwriter.conditional_format?

Tags: python, arrays, string, sorting

This is my code:

```
p2 = 'hello', 'hai','python', 'java','robotics'
p3 = ['hello','java']
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(p2)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('final.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

data_frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=-1)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format1 = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#9C0006'})

for o in p3:

    if o in p2: 

        worksheet.conditional_format(1, 1, len(data_frame), 0,
                                                 {'type':     'text',                             
                                                  'criteria': 'containing',
                                                  'value':    o,
                                                  'format':   format1}) 
writer.save()
```

output:
[image]

but when i add sentence instead of words:

```
p2 = ['hello', 'hai','python', 'java',"robotics"," If you are going to use a passage of 
Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle 
of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks 
as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary 
of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to 
generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. " ]

p3 = ['hello','java', 'robotics', " If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, 
you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All 
the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as 
necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of 
over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate 
Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. "]
```

i get this error while opening final.xlsx and there is no red marked sentence as i thought would be:

```
"we found a problem with some content in 'final.xlsx'" #<--- from 
                                                        #microsoft 
                                               #excel error message
```

what silly mistake am I doing ? please help thank you.

Comment: The issue is that the text that you are using for a match is too long. Excel only allows a maximum of 255 characters for the match string.

But let's take a step back first. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: oh i see, no, i just want to know why it didnt work. thank you, so only takes 255 ? are you sure ? because when i inserted 100 it gave the same error but up to 50 or 60 it worked.

Comment: You can verify the limit in Excel by copying in the string.